# boot of nfs mounting drive taking very long

Tags: boot, systemd, nfs

When I upgraded to ubuntu 16.04 my boot time increased dramatically I did a
**systemd-analyze blame** and as you can see the first two items take a very long time to load and this is on a SSD.

```
1min 30.147s home-test-nfsp.mount
1min 30.145s home-test-nfst.mount
          5.380s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
           554ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-9f7c7335\x2d05e4\x2d437f\x2dbe
           225ms dev-sda1.device
           211ms ModemManager.service
           208ms systemd-rfkill.service
           181ms grub-common.service
           174ms networking.service
           157ms systemd-logind.service
           153ms gpu-manager.service
           129ms systemd-localed.service
           118ms upower.service
           117ms udisks2.service
           117ms alsa-restore.service
           117ms lm-sensors.service
           114ms pppd-dns.service
```

I have the following lines in my /etc/fstab file

```
192.168.1.34:/media/tgh/1\040entertain/audio/  /home/test/nfst  nfs   soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192
192.168.1.34:/media/tgh/1\040entertain/youtube/1podtemp/  /home/test/nfsp  nfs   soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192
```

Why is NFS taking so long to boot?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When the service `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` is enabled it will ensure that all configured network devices are up and have an IP address assigned before boot continues. This service will time out after 90s. Enabling this service might considerably delay your boot even if the timeout is not reached.

Comment: That's great information but how does one change the timeout or disable this?

Comment: Maybe , If you change the delay , the service will fail according to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Enable_NetworkManager_Wait_Online